# How do I write a dynamic predicate builder for a where statement in linq / EF Core?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

I'm working with an `IQueryable<SomeRandomObject>` that is pulled using an EF Core 3.1 data context.

I'm pretty sure I can dynamically build a predicate for `.Where()` so that I can pass a string in for what column, and what value.

Of course this doesn't work, but some pseudo-code might be:

```
IQueryable myQueryable = stuffFromContext;
var columnName = "memberid";
var searchValue = "1234";
var results = myQueryable.Where(x=> someMagicColumnFunction(columnName, searchvalue))
```

I've only done research at this point, and predicate building is not my area of expertise.

Can someone help me create a function that I can pass in the parameters my `IQueryable`, a string representing the column name, and a string for the search (full equality for now, no 'like').

I'd love to see how this is done. I can't find a solid example anywhere on how to do something small like this. Most of the examples are everything and the kitchen sink!

Comment: Two resources come to mind: [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/), and [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Note that [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) pretty much supercedes Predicate Builder. @RobertHarvey

Comment: FYI, your `someMagicalColumnFunction` would need to replace the `Where` parameter - it must return the entire `Expression` for the lambda (otherwise, the `Where` parameter would be an `Expression` tree representing a lambda calling `someMagicalColumnFunction` which wouldn't be executed and just cause an EF translation error).

Comment: Also, `someMagicalColumnFunction` must be `myQueryable` specific since there is no parameter with the type of `x` passed into it - unless you write a `Where` replacement instead. (PS There is no `IQueryable.Where` so that won't work.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the type of the rows in `myQueryable` are `TQueryable` then you can create a `myQueryable` specific function to generate the lambda:

```
Expression<Func<TQueryable, bool>> EqualsFilter<TCol>(string columnName, TCol searchValue) {
    // build x => x.{columnName} == searchValue

    // (TQueryable x)
    var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TQueryable), "x");
    // x.{columnName}
    var colExpr = Expression.Property(xParam, columnName);
    // {searchValue}
    var constExpr = Expression.Constant(searchValue);
    // x.{columnName} == {searchValue}
    var lambdaBody = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, colExpr, constExpr);
    // (TQueryable x) => x.{columnName} == {searchValue}
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TQueryable, bool>>(lambdaBody, xParam);

    return lambda;
}
```

Once you have the method, you can use it like:

```
var myQueryable = stuffFromContext;
var columnName = "memberid";
var searchValue = "1234";
var results = myQueryable.Where(EqualsFilter(columnName, searchvalue));
```

However, if `myQueryable` has a complex or anonymous type (because of a `Select` or `Join`) you need to replace the `Where` as C# can only infer types from parameters, so you need the `myQueryable` parameter to get the entity type you are filtering. Using a generic version of `EqualsFilter` as a helper method, you have:

```
public static class IQueryableExt {
    static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualsFilter<T, TCol>(string columnName, TCol searchValue) {
        // build x => x.{columnName} == searchValue

        // (T x)
        var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Accounts), "x");
        // x.{columnName}
        var colExpr = Expression.Property(xParam, columnName);
        // {searchValue}
        var constExpr = Expression.Constant(searchValue);
        // x.{columnName} == {searchValue}
        var lambdaBody = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, colExpr, constExpr);
        // (T x) => x.{columnName} == {searchValue}
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(lambdaBody, xParam);

        return lambda;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereColumnEquals<T, TCol>(this IQueryable<T> src, string columnName, TCol searchValue)
        => src.Where(EqualsFilter<T, TCol>(columnName, searchValue));
}
```

Which you can now use like:

```
var myQueryable = stuffFromContext;
var columnName = "memberid";
var searchValue = "1234";
var results = myQueryable.WhereColumnEquals(columnName, searchvalue);
```